# List plot 3D not showing correct data

Tags: plotting

I have a list of values of the form `{{a_1,b_1,c_1},{a_2,b_2,c_2}...}` where `a` goes from 0 to 30, `b` goes from 0 to 30, and `c` goes from 0 to .05. For some reason, when I plot this using `ListPlot3D` I get ranges of 1 to 4, 0 to 40, and 0 to 500 respectively (the number of data points that I am plotting.

The exact command that I am using is: `ListPlot3D[data,PlotRange->{Full,Full,Full},AxesLabel->{"Length","Distance","Time"}]`

Does anyone know what might be the issue?

Note: If anyone wants to look at the actual data, I posted it [here](http://pastebin.com/n8bEcXMB).

Comment: In your data you give four elements $\{\{a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1\},...\}$ what's the last one for?

Comment: You can get only the first three using `data[[All, 1 ;; 3]]`

Comment: @Spawn1701D wow, not sure how I missed that

Comment: @PlatoManiac fixed it. Do you mind explaining why I got the behavior that I did in an answer?

Comment: @soandos if you check the manual you will see that you gave him to make the 3D plot of an array of height values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do you mind explaining why I got the behavior that I did in an answer?

There is more than one input syntax for `ListPlot3D`:

[image]

When you use data of the form `{{_, _, _, _} ..}` the last definition is used.

For example, with:

```
dat = Table[{x + Cos[x], x + Sin[x], Sqrt[x], x}, {x, 0, 30, 0.1}];
```

Of which the ranges are:

```
{Min@#, Max@#} & /@ Transpose[dat]
```

> ```
> {{1., 30.1543}, {0., 29.012}, {0., 5.47723}, {0., 30.}}
> ```

You will get a plot like:

[image]

This is displaying the values (axis 0,10,20,30) for each column (axis 1,2,3,4) over the `{x, 0, 30, 0.1}` slices (axis 0,100,200,300).